# Filtering Data with on click function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, filtering

I have two array objects that hold my d3.svg.symbol types which are circles, squares & triangles. Array #1 has multiple symbols which I plot across the canvas, whereas array #2 only holds three symbols aligned together.

My goal is to be able to click on array #2 to filter out all of the array #1 symbols that i dont want to see. e.g. Clicking a circle in array #2 would only mean circles are shown in array #1.

```
      var array1 = svg.selectAll(a.array1)
                   .data(json).enter().append("a")

          array1.transition().duration(1000)
             .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")" ;})


          array1.append('path')
                .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) {return shape [d.Country];}).size(120))


      var array2 = svg.selectAll(g.array2)
                     .data(filt)
                     .enter().append("g")
                     .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")" ;})

          array2.append("path")
          .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d){return d.shape;}).size(200))
          .attr("transform", "translate(-10, -5)")
```

So my query is how do I specify the click onto array#2 specific types as I have three. Therefore, I would like all to be clickable, but have a different outcome.

So far I have tried this just to try & select specific shapes in array#2

```
       array2.on("click", function(){    alert('success')  })
```

which just alerts when I click any of them, however when this is applied:

```
    array2.on("click", function(){ if (d3.svg.symbol().type('circle') === true) { return  alert('success') ;};  })
```

When I click the circle of array2 it doesnt alert at all.

It would be great if I could get some help - thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listener gets the current datum and index as arguments, see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on). You can also access the DOM element through `this`. You could use this like follows.

```
.on("click", function(d) {
   if(d.shape == "circle") { alert("success"); }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Lars Kotthoff, thanks for reply. But, that doesnt seem to work either - nothing shows. http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/17/

Comment: .on("click", function(d){ if (d.shape =='circle')  { return  alert('success') }  }) .. Appears to work fine. But How would I get it to filter the circles from the 1st dataset

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer. To get specific circles, you need to have some other attribute to filter on. You could of course compare the actual data value, but a better way would be e.g. to assign a CSS class.

Comment: Well, when you append the elements for the first data set, you simply do a `.attr("class", "data1")` or something like that and then you can select them as `.selectAll(".data1")`.